# Unit Test case for a method which adds object in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, core-data, testcase

I have a method which adds a Object in Customer Entity in my core data.
I Want to write a test case to check if after the execution of that method the new customer object is added in core data.

Here is the method which creates a new object and adds in Customer entity

```
-(void) setAddCustomerObject
{

Address *address = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Address" inManagedObjectContext:[[DataModelManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext]];
Contact *emailContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:[[DataModelManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext]];
Contact *landlineContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:[[DataModelManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext]];
Contact *mobileContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:[[DataModelManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext]];

_addCustomer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Customer" inManagedObjectContext:[[DataModelManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext]];

//set customer name
_addCustomer.firstName = _customerName;

if(_customerMobile){

    mobileContact.data = _customerMobile;
    mobileContact.type = MOBILE;
    [_addCustomer addContactsObject:mobileContact];
}

if(_customerLandline){

    landlineContact.data = _customerLandline;
    landlineContact.type = PHONE;
    [_addCustomer addContactsObject:landlineContact];
}

if(_customerEmail){

    emailContact.data = _customerEmail;
    emailContact.type = EMAIL;
    [_addCustomer addContactsObject:emailContact];
}

//set Address
address.addressLine1 = _customerAddressLine1;
address.addressLine2 = _customerAddressLine2;
address.pinCode = _customerPinCode;
_addCustomer.address = address;


if([[[WrapperManager sharedManager] customerWrap] getDefaultCategoryForCustomer]){

    _addCustomer.category = [[[WrapperManager sharedManager] customerWrap] getDefaultCategoryForCustomer];
}


//set customer type and geography
[_addCustomer addGeographiesObject:_geography];
_addCustomer.type = _customertype;

    _addCustomer.active = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

    //save the context
    NSError *error;
    [[[DataModelManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext] save:&error];
}
```

m still confused on how do i test this method ? any solutions?

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: I Want to write a test case to check if after the execution of that method the new customer object is added in core data.
How do i do it ?

Comment: I think you need to specify what tools/frameworks etc you want to use for your testing - give some examples of other test cases you have written etc.

Comment: One approach is to have a "known" dataset do the insert and then query the datastore and compare the result to the known dataset ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Create object, save
2. Fetch object
3. Assert that the content is what you expect

Comment: The method above creates the object and saves itself. I want to check if this method saves the object successfully.After the object is Added to core data, that object data is sent to server and saved on server. 
So now when i run my test case it pases the test case but it creates the object and sends it to server. which means everytime i run that test case the dummy object will b sent to server and saved there which is not i want for test case.

Comment: What's the problem? If you don't want to send it, don't send it.